# Get world position in shader of Unity's new PostProcessing stack?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

How would one in Unity's new PostProcessing shader framework get the absolute xyz world position of the pixel in question? Many thanks!

```
Shader "Hidden/Filter/Test" {
    HLSLINCLUDE
        #include "../../PostProcessing/Shaders/StdLib.hlsl"
        TEXTURE2D_SAMPLER2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex);
        float4 Frag(VaryingsDefault i) : SV_Target {
            float4 color = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex, i.texcoordStereo);

            // what's the world position of this color pixel ...?

            return color;
        }
    ENDHLSL
    SubShader {
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always
        Pass {
            HLSLPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex VertDefault
                #pragma fragment Frag
            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at these links: [How to get the position of current pixel in screen space](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-get-position-of-current-pixel-in-screen-space-in-framgment-shader-function.219843/) & [Screenspace to Worldspace](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-get-position-of-current-pixel-in-screen-space-in-framgment-shader-function.219843/).

Comment: If you pass in a depth buffer, you can reverse the camera's projection matrix to calculate world position of each fragment.

Comment: Ian, thanks, my issue is that whenever I try to copy & paste from these various examples, I get a multitude of random errors (for instance, following your link now, "undeclared identifier 'UNITY_MATRIX_MVP' at line 27 (on d3d11)", but that's just one of many), and I'm going down a rabbit hole of error after error. Do you happen to have a full example that works with the PostProcessing2Beta framework?

Comment: Rutter, that sounds very interesting, do you have a working code sample? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not working with shaders too much at the moment, so no I do not have an example. But the _undeclared identifier_ error could result from Unity having discarded it and replaced it with something else.

Comment: You're missing an `#include "UnityCG.cginc"` which is require for most in-built features including access to `UNITY_*` macros.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that first, and it threw another error ("... redefinition of '_Time' at /Program Files/Unity 2018.1.0b10/Editor/Data/CGIncludes/UnityShaderVariables.cginc ..."). I wish there was a full shader example that works in PostProcessing2 Beta...

Comment: please edit your question and add your cg shader and tell me convert this to postprocessing stack.

Answer (score 8):

Lece said right In your comments:

> You're missing an #include `"UnityCG.cginc"` which is require for most in-built features including access to `UNITY_*` macros.

but problem Is when you use  `"UnityCG.cginc"` PostProcessing stack 2 confilict with the same functions In Unity built-in shader.so I decide to find It In standard shader unity:

In [Unity Archive shader](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) you can find `UNITY_MATRIX_MVP` In `Standard\CGIncludes\UnityShaderVariables.cginc`

```
#define UNITY_MATRIX_MVP mul(unity_MatrixVP, unity_ObjectToWorld)
```

---

## Using World Space

```
Shader "Hidden/Filter/Test" {
    HLSLINCLUDE
        #include "../../PostProcessing/Shaders/StdLib.hlsl"
        #define UNITY_MATRIX_MVP mul(unity_MatrixVP, unity_ObjectToWorld)
        
        TEXTURE2D_SAMPLER2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex);

                struct v2f {
                  float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                  float3 worldPos : TEXCOORD0;
                  float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD1;
                  float2 texcoordStereo : TEXCOORD2;
              };

            struct appdata {
                  float4 vertex : POSITION;
              };

            v2f VertDefault(appdata v) {
                  v2f o;
  
                  o.worldPos = mul (unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
                  o.vertex = float4(v.vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
                  o.texcoord = TransformTriangleVertexToUV(v.vertex.xy);

                #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
                    o.texcoord = o.texcoord * float2(1.0, -1.0) + float2(0.0, 1.0);
                #endif

                    o.texcoordStereo = TransformStereoScreenSpaceTex(o.texcoord, 1.0);
                  return o;
              }

              float4 Frag(v2f i) : SV_Target {
                  float worldPos = i.worldPos;

                  float4 color = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex, i.texcoordStereo);

                  return float4(i.worldPos,1);
              }


            ENDHLSL
            SubShader {
            Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always
            Pass {
            HLSLPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex VertDefault
                #pragma fragment Frag


            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Adding World Position to StdLib.hlsl

Also you can add worldpos to `StdLib.hlsl` , you can find It In `PostProcessing-2\Assets\PostProcessing\Shaders` then change these lines:

I fixed `StdLib.hlsl` and I put [here](https://gist.github.com/smkplus/a45a6a83802b035a4b5baa1787427ba9)

```
#define UNITY_MATRIX_MVP mul(unity_MatrixVP, unity_ObjectToWorld)

struct VaryingsDefault
{
    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
    float2 texcoordStereo : TEXCOORD1;
    float3 worldPos : TEXCOORD2;
};

VaryingsDefault VertDefault(AttributesDefault v)
{
    VaryingsDefault o;
    o.vertex = float4(v.vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    o.texcoord = TransformTriangleVertexToUV(v.vertex.xy);
    o.worldPos = mul (unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);

#if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
    o.texcoord = o.texcoord * float2(1.0, -1.0) + float2(0.0, 1.0);
#endif

    o.texcoordStereo = TransformStereoScreenSpaceTex(o.texcoord, 1.0);

    return o;
}
```

In this way using World Space Is Easy!

```
Shader "Hidden/Filter/Test" {
    HLSLINCLUDE
        #include "../../PostProcessing/Shaders/StdLib.hlsl"

        float4 Frag(VaryingsDefault i) : SV_Target {
            return float4(i.worldPos,1);//Using World Position!
        }


            ENDHLSL
            SubShader {
            Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always
            Pass {
            HLSLPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex VertDefault
                #pragma fragment Frag


            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Update

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMOOcmp6FrM

Attach this script to your camera:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class DepthBuffToWorldPosDemo : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Material material;
        private new Camera camera;
        private new Transform transform;
    
        private void Start()
        {
            camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
            transform = GetComponent<Transform>();
        }
    
         void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
        {
    
            // NOTE: code was ported from: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131978/shader-reconstructing-position-from-depth-in-vr-through-projection-matrix
    
            var p = GL.GetGPUProjectionMatrix(camera.projectionMatrix, false);
            p[2, 3] = p[3, 2] = 0.0f;
            p[3, 3] = 1.0f;
            var clipToWorld = Matrix4x4.Inverse(p * camera.worldToCameraMatrix) * Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(0, 0, -p[2,2]), Quaternion.identity, Vector3.one);
            material.SetMatrix("clipToWorld", clipToWorld);
    
            Graphics.Blit(source, destination, material);
    
        }

}
```

you can use Unity shader or Postprocessing shader

Unity Shader:

```
Shader "Hidden/DepthBuffToWorldPos"
{

    SubShader
    {
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 5.0
            
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float3 worldDirection : TEXCOORD1;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            float4x4 clipToWorld;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;

                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;

                float4 clip = float4(o.vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
                o.worldDirection = mul(clipToWorld, clip) - _WorldSpaceCameraPos;

                return o;
            }
            
            sampler2D_float _CameraDepthTexture;
            float4 _CameraDepthTexture_ST;

            float4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                float depth = SAMPLE_DEPTH_TEXTURE(_CameraDepthTexture, i.uv.xy);
                depth = LinearEyeDepth(depth);
                float3 worldspace = i.worldDirection * depth + _WorldSpaceCameraPos;

                float4 color = float4(worldspace, 1.0);
                return color;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Postprocessing stack Shader

```
Shader "Hidden/Filter/Test" {
        HLSLINCLUDE
             #include "../../PostProcessing/Shaders/StdLib.hlsl"
            #define UNITY_MATRIX_MVP mul(unity_MatrixVP, unity_ObjectToWorld)
            #include "HLSLSupport.cginc"
            #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_nicest

            TEXTURE2D_SAMPLER2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex);
            float4x4 clipToWorld;



                    struct v2f {
                      float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                     float3 worldDirection : TEXCOORD0;
                      float3 screenPos : TEXCOORD1;
                      float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD2;
                      float2 texcoordStereo : TEXCOORD3;

                  };
    
                struct appdata {
                      float4 vertex : POSITION;
                  };

                            sampler2D_float _CameraDepthTexture;
            float4 _CameraDepthTexture_ST;
    
                v2f VertDefault(appdata v) {
                      v2f o;
      
                      o.vertex = float4(v.vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
                      o.texcoord = TransformTriangleVertexToUV(v.vertex.xy);

                                    float4 clip = float4(o.vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
                o.worldDirection = mul(clipToWorld, clip) - _WorldSpaceCameraPos;
    
                    #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
                        o.texcoord = o.texcoord * float2(1.0, -1.0) + float2(0.0, 1.0);
                    #endif

                      // Correct flip when rendering with a flipped projection matrix.
                      // (I've observed this differing between the Unity scene & game views)
                      o.screenPos.y *= _ProjectionParams.x;
                      o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                      o.screenPos = o.vertex.xyw;
    
                        o.texcoordStereo = TransformStereoScreenSpaceTex(o.texcoord, 1.0);
                      return o;
                  }
    
                  float4 Frag(v2f i) : SV_Target {
                float2 screenUV = (i.screenPos.xy / i.screenPos.z) * 0.5f + 0.5f;
                float depth = SAMPLE_DEPTH_TEXTURE(_CameraDepthTexture,screenUV);
                depth = LinearEyeDepth(depth);
                float3 worldspace = i.worldDirection * depth + _WorldSpaceCameraPos;
                
                float4 color = float4(worldspace, 1.0);
                return color;
                  }
    
    
                ENDHLSL
                SubShader {
                Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always
                Pass {
                HLSLPROGRAM
                    #pragma vertex VertDefault
                    #pragma fragment Frag
    
    
                ENDHLSL
            }
        }
    }
```

---

## Adding World Position to StdLib.hlsl

[StdLibFixed.hlsl](https://gist.github.com/smkplus/dcc6aa7c03b17f87724e6c73b9dffe81)

```
#define UNITY_MATRIX_MVP mul(unity_MatrixVP, unity_ObjectToWorld)
#include "HLSLSupport.cginc"
#pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_nicest

float4x4 clipToWorld;


struct VaryingsDefault
{
float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
float3 worldDirection : TEXCOORD0;
float3 screenPos : TEXCOORD1;
float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD2;
float2 texcoordStereo : TEXCOORD3;
};



    sampler2D_float _CameraDepthTexture;
float4 _CameraDepthTexture_ST;



VaryingsDefault VertDefault(AttributesDefault v)
{
VaryingsDefault o;

o.vertex = float4(v.vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
o.texcoord = TransformTriangleVertexToUV(v.vertex.xy);

float4 clip = float4(o.vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
o.worldDirection = mul(clipToWorld, clip) - _WorldSpaceCameraPos;

#if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
o.texcoord = o.texcoord * float2(1.0, -1.0) + float2(0.0, 1.0);
#endif

// Correct flip when rendering with a flipped projection matrix.
// (I've observed this differing between the Unity scene & game views)
o.screenPos.y *= _ProjectionParams.x;
o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
o.screenPos = o.vertex.xyw;


o.texcoordStereo = TransformStereoScreenSpaceTex(o.texcoord, 1.0);
return o;
}
```

In this way using World Space Is Easy!

```
Shader "Hidden/Filter/Test" {
        HLSLINCLUDE
            #include "../StdLib.hlsl"
           
    
                  float4 Frag(v2f i) : SV_Target {
                float2 screenUV = (i.screenPos.xy / i.screenPos.z) * 0.5f + 0.5f;
                float depth = SAMPLE_DEPTH_TEXTURE(_CameraDepthTexture,screenUV);
                depth = LinearEyeDepth(depth);
                float3 worldspace = i.worldDirection * depth + _WorldSpaceCameraPos;
                
                float4 color = float4(worldspace, 1.0);
                return color;
                  }
    
    
                ENDHLSL
                SubShader {
                Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always
                Pass {
                HLSLPROGRAM
                    #pragma vertex VertDefault
                    #pragma fragment Frag
    
    
                ENDHLSL
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I can't get the "i.texcoordStereo" anymore to grab the color at that world position, as in "float4 color = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex, i.texcoordStereo);"? Help please?

Comment: Another question, do I need to put UnityShaderVariables.cginc into my project? Or was that just for reference/ information, and I don't need it?

Comment: @PhilippLenssen No I just use `#define UNITY_MATRIX_MVP mul(unity_MatrixVP, unity_ObjectToWorld)` In above shader.Test one of the above shaders It should work corretly.

Comment: @PhilippLenssen I fixed It please test It.

Comment: Thank you! This fixes textcoordStereo not being found, but i.worldPos now still doesn't apply to the fixed absolute worldPos -- but to the relative screen position, based on where the camera points. So if I use the following for instance, then it will always paint the lower half of the camera view black, independent of the actual object world positions:         float4 Frag(v2f i) : SV_Target {
            float4 color = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex, i.texcoordStereo);
            if (i.worldPos.y > 0) { color = float4(0,0,0,1); }
            return color;
        } Help?

Comment: @PhilippLenssen I will fix It but can you send an Image that what describe what you want exactly because? I can not imagine what you are looking for without Image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169312/discussion-between-seyed-morteza-kamali-and-philipp-lenssen).

Comment: Thank you! I do not have time until Monday to fully test your update, so I'm already awarding you the bounty, as it needs to be awarded within the next hours. I will also mark yours as answer once I can confirm it. Thanks so much for the great work!

Comment: @PhilippLenssen thanks :D I'm waiting for you to testing.I will do my best to solving your problem.

Comment: I've tried your code now (the Postprocessing variant), but it asks me to set a material for DepthBuffToWorldPosDemo -- I want that filter to be screenwide though, unrelated to any specific object or material. Help please? Thanks!

Comment: 1.Attach DepthBuffToWorldPosDemo.cs to your camera 2.create a material and use `Postprocessing stack Shader` In my answer then set It to the DepthBuffToWorldPosDemo's material

Comment: What should I do with this material, which object/ mesh is it applied to? I require the scene to be free of new materials, as it's an open sandbox universe where there's already up to 3 material layers, so... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had a lot of issue with this and not sure if this is a fix for everyone (testing Mac w/ Metal in 2017.3.1p1) but I had the same issue as above - moving or rotating the camera would cause the world space position to change very strangely.

I tested with the old method (not integrated with Post Processing stack) detailed here and this works. - https://github.com/zezba9000/UnityMathReference/tree/master/Assets/Shaders/DepthBuffToWorldPos

Recreating the same in the Post Processing stack gave me different results. After some poking around I found the only data different was `i.worldDirection` which is based off the `v.vertex.xy` by default. I changed this to be `i.texcoord.xy*2-1` and it works perfectly for me.

---

**Here is the code (cs+shader)**:

`DrawWorldSpacePosition.cs`

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing;

[Serializable]
[PostProcess(typeof(DrawWorldSpacePositionRenderer), PostProcessEvent.AfterStack, "Custom/DrawWorldSpacePosition")]
public sealed class DrawWorldSpacePosition : PostProcessEffectSettings
{
}

public sealed class DrawWorldSpacePositionRenderer : PostProcessEffectRenderer<DrawWorldSpacePosition>
{
    public override void Render(PostProcessRenderContext context)
    {
        var sheet = context.propertySheets.Get(Shader.Find("Hidden/Custom/DrawWorldSpacePosition"));

        var camera = context.camera;

        var p = GL.GetGPUProjectionMatrix(camera.projectionMatrix, false);// Unity flips its 'Y' vector depending on if its in VR, Editor view or game view etc... (facepalm)
        p[2, 3] = p[3, 2] = 0.0f;
        p[3, 3] = 1.0f;
        var clipToWorld = Matrix4x4.Inverse(p * camera.worldToCameraMatrix) * Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(0, 0, -p[2, 2]), Quaternion.identity, Vector3.one);
        sheet.properties.SetMatrix("clipToWorld", clipToWorld);

        context.command.BlitFullscreenTriangle(context.source, context.destination, sheet, 0);
    }
}
```

`DrawWorldSpacePosition.shader`

```
Shader "Hidden/Custom/DrawWorldSpacePosition"
{
    HLSLINCLUDE

        #include "../PostProcessing/Shaders/StdLib.hlsl"

        TEXTURE2D_SAMPLER2D(_CameraDepthTexture, sampler_CameraDepthTexture);

        uniform float4x4 clipToWorld;

        struct VaryingsExtended
        {
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            float2 texcoordStereo : TEXCOORD1;
            float3 worldDirection : TEXCOORD2;
        };

        VaryingsExtended Vert(AttributesDefault v)
        {
            VaryingsExtended o;
            o.vertex = float4(v.vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
            o.texcoord = TransformTriangleVertexToUV(v.vertex.xy);

        #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
            o.texcoord = o.texcoord * float2(1.0, -1.0) + float2(0.0, 1.0);
        #endif

            o.texcoordStereo = TransformStereoScreenSpaceTex(o.texcoord, 1.0);

            float4 clip = float4(o.texcoord.xy*2-1, 0.0, 1.0);
            o.worldDirection = mul(clipToWorld, clip) - _WorldSpaceCameraPos;
            return o;
        }

        float4 Frag(VaryingsExtended i) : SV_Target
        {
            float depth = SAMPLE_DEPTH_TEXTURE(_CameraDepthTexture, sampler_CameraDepthTexture, i.texcoordStereo);
            depth = LinearEyeDepth(depth);
            float3 worldspace = i.worldDirection * depth + _WorldSpaceCameraPos;

            float4 color = float4(worldspace, 1.0);
            return color;
        } 

    ENDHLSL

    SubShader
    {
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass
        {
            HLSLPROGRAM 

                #pragma vertex Vert
                #pragma fragment Frag

            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `i.texcoord.xy*2-1` worked for me as well. But by now I have **no clue** what I'm doing. Even the original "DepthBuffToWorldPos" was full of magic, but now it feels like I'm really just adding random multiplications. 

Comment: It is kind of odd because `TransformTriangleVertexToUv` does exactly the opposite: `float2 uv = (vertex + 1.0) * 0.5;` 
So I'd guess that using `v.vertex.xy` would just work.